# Use selected item in table

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have two tables `POSITION_ACCOUNT` and `POSITION_TRANSACTION` they are mapped and `PARENT_ID` column in `POSITION_TRANSACTION` is a foreign key to `ID` column of `POSITION_ACCOUNT` table. What I do in my application is I run `LoroNostroController` where 'POSITION_ACCOUNT' table fields are listed. In this controller class I put this:

```
@FXML
@LinkAction(LoroNostroTrController.class)
private Button btn_next_button;
```

when I click this button, it goes to another controller class `LoroNostroTrController` where fields of `POSITION_TRANSACTION` table are listed.

What I want is when I select row from `LoroNostroController` class and press `btn_next_button` button, `LoroNostroTrController` will display rows

```
where POSITION_ACCOUNT.ID = POSITION_TRANSACTION.PARENT_ID 
and POSITION_TRANSACTION.PARENT_ID = selectedRowID
```

I can't get the logic where and how I can do that. How can I get ID of selectedRow in `LoroNostroTrController` class? Any ideas? I'll put any required code samples on demand. Thanks

Comment: I don't use DataFX, but I think to do this you have to store the selected item from the table in a model (you could use a property in the model and bind to it), and make the model available to the two controllers. Have a look at [this example](http://www.javafxdata.org/overview_flow.html), particularly the way the `FlowContext` is used to register and access a model to share data.